# How to translate active record model validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, internationalization

When I submit a form with an error in it, it returns an error message. How can I translate these error messages with i18n? I already have translation for all the other texts in my views, so I know how l18n works in Rails. I now get this:

```
2 errors prohibited this user from being saved:

Email translation missing: nl.activerecord.errors.models.user.attributes.email.blank
Email translation missing: nl.activerecord.errors.models.user.attributes.email.blank
```

I want to translate both the title and the errors.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The translation for the title would be:

```
nl:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      template:
        header:
          one:   "1 error prohibited this %{model} from being saved"
          other: "%{count} errors prohibited this %{model} from being saved"
        body:    "There were problems with the following fields:"
```

For translating the error messages, Rails will use the following order of translations:

```
activerecord.errors.models.user.attributes.name.blank
activerecord.errors.models.user.blank
activerecord.errors.messages.blank
errors.attributes.name.blank
errors.messages.blank
```

So you could add:

```
nl:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            email:
              blank: "foo blank in nl bar baz"
```

It's documented in the [Rails Internationalization (I18n) API Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models), which might give you some more insight.

Answer (score 26):

Just use the Dutch translations file that you can [find here](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/nl.yml). It contains translations for most (if not all) ActiveRecord validation messages.

Copy the file to `config/locales/` in your project.

**Alternate method**

If you want to benefit from updated translations, add the following to your `Gemfile` instead of copying the translation files by hand:

```
gem 'rails-i18n'
```

Comment: It's usually the first thing I do when creating a new rails app, do you know if there's a way to do it automatically?

Comment: No idea, really! Start a new question for it ;)

Comment: This plugin looks quite nice: https://github.com/zargony/rails-i18n-updater, I didn't test it though.

Comment: @Benoit, simply add the `rails-i18n` gem to your Gemfile.

Comment: @molf duh, so obvious I didn't even think of it. Thanks!

Comment: Also, there is a similar gem called `devise-i18n` with all the translations for devise.

Answer (score 13):

The [rails I18n guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models) covers this pretty well.

You can put the following in `config/locales/nl.yml` to translate the attributes:

```
nl:
  activerecord:
    models:
      user: "User"
    attributes:
      email: "Email"
```

For the error messages, ActiveRecord will look them up in the following namespaces:

```
activerecord.errors.models.[model_name].attributes.[attribute_name]
activerecord.errors.models.[model_name]
activerecord.errors.messages
errors.attributes.[attribute_name]
errors.messages
```

`model`, `attribute` and `value` are interpolated and available in your translations, for example:

```
nl:
  errors:
    messages:
      blank: "Please fill the %{model}'s %{attribute}"
```