# How do I add this translation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sharetribe

I am working on a Sharetribe website. I added the following line to my `person.rb` file:

```
validates_presence_of :address_line_1, on: :update
```

But when the error notification message appears, it says `translation missing: en.layouts.notifications.[:address_line_1, "can't be blank"]`

I've searched online and I can't see how I should add this translation?

FYI, Sharetribe runs on Ruby 2.1.2 and Rails 3.2.21.

Comment: Have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686013/how-to-translate-active-record-model-validations

Comment: looks like you need to add translation on your yaml file with this structure: en -> activerecord -> models -> errors -> layouts -> notification -> address_line_1 -> blank with value that you want

Answer (score 1):

All the locales are defined in 'config/locales/en.yml' file. 
Add the translation for error in the file like below:

```
layouts:
  notifications:
    address_blank_error: "Address line 1 can't be blank"
```

And, In your people_controller.rb update the code to:

```
def update
  . 
  .
 if target_user.update_attributes(.....)
   .....
 else
   if target_user.errors[:address_line_1].present?
     flash[:error] = t("layouts.notifications.address_blank_error")
   else
     flash[:error] = t("layouts.notifications.#{target_user.errors.first}")
   end
 end
```